# Strange issue running hiveql using -e option from .sh file

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have checked Stackoverflow but could not find any help and that is the reason i m posting a new question.

Issue is related executing hiveql using -e option from .sh file.

If i run hive as `$ bin/hive` everything works fine and properly all databases and tables are displayed.

If i run hive as `$ ./hive` OR `$ hive` (as set in path variable) OR `$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive` only default database is displayed that too without any table information.

I m learning hive and trying to execute hive command using `$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -e` from `.sh` file but it always give database not found.

So i understand that it is something related to reading of metadata but i m not able to understand why this kind of behavior.

However hadoop commands work fine from anywhere.

Below is one command i m trying to execute from `.sh` file

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -e 'LOAD DATA INPATH hdfs://myhost:8040/user/hduser/sample_table INTO TABLE rajen.sample_table'
```

Information:

I m using hive-0.13.0, hadoop-1.2.1

Can anybody pl explain me how to solve this or how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to fix the issue.

Issue was that i have kept the default derby setup of hive metadatastore_db , so from where ever i used to trigger hive -e command, it used to create a new copy of metadata_db copy.

So i created metadata store in mysql which became global and so now from where ever i trigger hive -e command, same metadata store db was being used.

Answer (score 3):

can you correct the query first, hive expect load statement path should be followed by quotes.
try this first from shell- **HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -e "LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/hduser/sample_table' INTO TABLE rajen.sample_table"**

or put your command in test.hql file and test $hive -f test.hql

---

--test.hql

LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/hduser/sample_table' INTO TABLE rajen.sample_table

---

Comment: Actually a simple command like HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -e "show databases" is not working, whereas same command is working if i execute as bin/hive -e "show databases". Anyways i have modified the command in my .sh file. Thanks for drawing my attention to such silly mistakes.